# $ T(n)= T(\log n)+ \mathcal O(1) $ Recurrence Relation

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms, recursion

what is the solution of following recurrence relation?
$$\begin{align}
T(1) &= 1\\
T(n) &= T(\log n) + \mathcal O(1)
\end{align}$$

a) $O(log n)$

b) $ O (log^* n) $

c) $ O (log^2 n) $

d) $ O (n / log n) $

Comment: What do you need to find? $T(n)$ as explicit function of $n$?

Comment: I would say this is more of a functional equation then recurrence relation since $\log n$ is not integer for $n$ being integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to think of recurrences of the form $T(n) = T(f(n)) + \Theta(1)$<sup>†</sup> as "accumulator" recurrences.  This is because they "add up" the number of iterations--or some multiple thereof--it takes for $f(n)$ to go beyond some limit.

In words, this recurrence is determining the number of times one must take a logarithm before reaching $1$.  This should sound familiar to a computer science student, as there's a special function to describe this number!

This special function is  $\lg^*n$, which is the [iterated logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm).  Since some may not be familiar with this function, it is defined as:
$$\lg^*n:=\begin{cases}
0& n\leq 1\\
1+\lg^*(\lg(n)) & n > 1
\end{cases}$$

So, a good guess would be that $T(n) \in \Theta(\lg^*n)$.  (In fact, if we had $+1$ instead of $+\Theta(1)$, the exact solution would be: $T(n) = \lg^* n + 1$.)  The guess can be proven somewhat easily using strong induction.

---

<sup>†</sup>I must make an important distinction: if you are really talking about big-$\mathcal O$ notation, there isn't a unique "right answer" to this question.  This is because $\mathcal O(\cdot )$ is *an upper bound* for the asymptotic behavior of the recurrence, rather than a tight bound.  People often confuse $\mathcal O(\cdot)$ with $\Theta(\cdot)$.  As such, I'm assuming that the you meant $\Theta(\cdot)$ wherever you wrote $\mathcal O(\cdot)$.

Comment: @David If you really meant to use big-O notation (e.g. $O(\lg n) $), there is more than one correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know how to do this is to solve by guess and inductive proof. For example, you're already wondering if the function is $\mathcal{O}(log(n))$.

$T(n) \in \mathcal{O}(f(n))$ if there exist constants $c$, $n_0>0$ such that $T(n) \leq cf(n))$ for all $n >n_0$.

I'm going to replace the $O(1)$ with 1 (you can do this with an unspecified constant too). 
So I'm going to assume log base 2, and I'm going to assert that $T(n) \leq 2lg(n)$. My $n_0 =2$. $T(2) =  T(1)+ 1 = 2 \leq 2lg(2) =2$ holds.
Assume this holds for all $n'< n$
Then (working backwards): $T(n) = T(lg(n))+1 \leq 2lg(lg(n))+1= 2lg(lg(n) \sqrt{2})$. Now we need to show $lg(n) \sqrt{2} \leq n$ (it is).

Another way to solve is to solve by unrolling: Starting with $n$, how many times can you take the log until you get to 1? About $log(n)$ times. Write out the sum for what will happen at each step, and you'll notice you get a sum of a constant $log(n)$ times. I'd still use the inductive proof to show that it's true.

Also, there's the master theorem, but I wasn't sure how to apply it in this case.

Comment: The master theorem/Akra-Bazzi method won't work here because there is no term of $T(cn)$ (or "morally" $T(cn)$, in the Akra-Bazzi method).

Comment: I didn't. big-O means that there is more than one answer. I picked one and showed that it was true. You had a few guesses, so try the inductive proof with $O(log^*(n))$. However, my wording wasn't good--instead of saying "about $log(n)$ times" I should have said "up to $log(n)$ times" (and yes, $log^*(n)$ is a tighter bound).