# how to solve T(n)=T(Logn)+O(1)

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

Given That $T(1)=1$
Solve following recurrence function
$T(n)=T(\log n)+O(1)$

I know the answer is $\log^* n$ but don't know how to prove it.
What I tried:
$\log(n)+\log(n-1)+\log(n-2)+...+1 = \log(n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...)=\log n!$ If I am at the right track what to do next?

Thanks.

P.S:
This question is same as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145030/tn-t-log-n-mathcal-o1-recurrence-relation) but the answer states:

> " The guess can be proven somewhat easily using strong induction."

without providing the proof.

Comment: The idea is already there: the number of steps taken in the recurrence is the number of times you need to apply $\log$ to $n$ to get it to be less than $1$. This is $\log^*(n)$ by definition. Then you add a bounded number at each step, so what you get is bounded by some multiple of $\log^*(n)$, i.e. it is $O(\log^*(n))$.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Its $\log\log\log\log\log..n$. Thanks.

Comment: It's not the result of applying log a bunch of times, it's a bounded number times the number of times you had to apply the log.